# android : NoClassDefFoundError for android 4.4 and below

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-4.4-kitkat

My app gives `NoClassDefFoundError`  for versions of sdk 19 or below.
I had in my gradle

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.idg.mail"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

Now i tried to change it to

```
compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.idg.gatcamail"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

i changed in `app-> module settings - android - sdk` as well.
With these changes i built the project but still it gives same error on  my `android 4.4` and it runs on higher versions.

The class is a class defined in the code where i handle network operations.

How can i do the debugging of this issue

Comment: For what class do you have the exception?

Comment: its a java class that i have defined which mainly does the job of fetching data from server

Comment: It might be also caused by the `multiDexEnabled` option. Are you sure that it have to be set to true and what are dependencies?

Comment: @preetha, In your manifest which application tag are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm almost sure that it is multidex issue. If it's running properly on sdk 21 - it's multidex issue.

Here is official info: [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

If you're using custom implementation of Application class, it has to extend MultiDexApplication class. Also there is gradle flag required. If you're not using custom Application class, just add entry provided in your manifest - it's described in documentation.

Edit: Almost forgot - you've to add dependency, multidex is provided with this library: `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Comment: @Tuff, yes you can

Comment: i was already having gradle flags but the application class was not changed. How that works on > sdk-21. With this change , its working on both versions.. but how it worked before on higher versions

Comment: @preetha Multidex is Dalvik issue, on Android 5+ there is ART instead Dalvik. So on api 21+ there is no 64k method limit :)

Comment: But if i remeber correctly if i do not set these flags in gradle , even for higher versions, i was getting errors. dex related. Thats where i had set the flags. Is that normal

Comment: I don't remember but I think that it's related to minSdk value, it has to be set to 21

Comment: Yes tested and verified. for minsdk < 21 it gives dexindexoverflow exception, but works on higher version with no flag . thank you