# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after installing app from Fabric Beta

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

When I compile my app directly, it works on every devices. But when I make a build through Fabric and install my app from the Fabric Beta app I got this crash right after starting my app :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.AppInfo
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:229)
    at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4720)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This occurs only on devices version 4.4 and lower. I also had trouble related to [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/beta-cant-upload-apk-after-upgrading-android-studio-2-1/65931). Do you think the crash I got is related?

this is my project build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio version 2.0 or above then you should disable instant run & try to build again.

Instant Run tries to do hot swapping of your code; this causes the application class to be moved.

To disable Instant Run Go to 
File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck "Enable instant run"

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with the question posted.

Comment: Hi, @EthanHolshouser Instant run was bit buggy at that time and build was not generating incremental builds properly.It's actually a good tool to save a development time.

You can find more info about instant runs here: https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError - usually it's related to multidex issues. Check this answer: [Multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889914/android-noclassdeffounderror-for-android-4-4-and-below/36891001#36891001)

Comment: Should I receive this error when I compile and run the app directly on those phone ?

Comment: @Tuff I'm not sure, maybe fabric build add some code (libraries) and with that you're exceeding 64k limit. You can try to run dex-method-count script against both apk files and compare results. Anyway I would try fix above before, it takes only 2mins to adjust your code with multidex.

Comment: @Tuff looks like this issue is reported here [Bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199784) and similar one here: [Bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199327) Second one is more interesting because some ppl saying that upgrading AS to 2.1 with plugin helped.